# Masked Passwords in declarative Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**Declarative Pipeline password parameters**: Below code hide the password on UI page but it display the password parameters in build logs . How to hide it in jenkins logs also.

```
parameters {
password(name: 'myPwd', defaultValue: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", description: 'Secret Access key of the environment')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using password, use credentials
and this credential has to be added in Jenkins Credentials

```
key = credentials("USER_KEY")
```